# TikZ: rotating scope changes the shading, but not how you'd expect

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, shading, scoping

It is my understanding that the shading in the following code is applied after the scope transformation.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{myshade}{2cm}{
    color(0cm)=(red);
    color(.3cm)=(orange);
    color(.6cm)=(yellow);
    color(.9cm)=(green);
    color(1.2cm)=(blue);
    color(1.5cm)=(purple);
    color(1.8cm)=(brown)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=26.73]
    \draw [shading=myshade] (0, 0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \draw [shading=myshade] (0, 0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Given that a circle is symmetrical by rotation, the result of both tikzpictures should be the same. Yet the shading is different. Why is this the case?

[image]

Comment: The shading is done on the basis of the bounding box. A circle is constructed from Bezier curves, and this means that [its bounding box changes under rotations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426285/194703). As you can see, the circles are not vertically aligned either, for the same reason.

Comment: [Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/486065/108724)?

Answer (score 3):

The shading is done on the basis of the bounding box, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/486065/108724). A circle is constructed from Bezier curves, and this means that [its bounding box changes under rotations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426285/194703). As you can see, the circles are not vertically aligned either, for the same reason. Once you fix the bounding box, the effect is gone.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{myshade}{2cm}{
    color(0cm)=(red);
    color(.3cm)=(orange);
    color(.6cm)=(yellow);
    color(.9cm)=(green);
    color(1.2cm)=(blue);
    color(1.5cm)=(purple);
    color(1.8cm)=(brown)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]
\begin{scope}[rotate=26.73]
    \draw [shading=myshade] (0, 0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]
\begin{scope}
    \draw [shading=myshade] (0, 0) circle (1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to rotate the shading, change the `shading angle`. (You can also use `transform canvas` but this is sometimes a bit hard to tame.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{myshade}{2cm}{
    color(0cm)=(red);
    color(.3cm)=(orange);
    color(.6cm)=(yellow);
    color(.9cm)=(green);
    color(1.2cm)=(blue);
    color(1.5cm)=(purple);
    color(1.8cm)=(brown)
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]
\path (0, 0) circle[radius=1];
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=26.73}]
    \draw [shading=myshade] (0, 0) circle[radius=1];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]
\begin{scope}
    \draw [shading=myshade,shading angle=26.73] (0, 0) circle[radius=1];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]
\begin{scope}
    \draw [shading=myshade] (0, 0) circle[radius=1];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP's question is about rotating the inside color and not about bounding box! Isn't?

Comment: @C.F.G The question reads: "Given that a circle is symmetrical by rotation, the result of both tikzpictures should be the same. Yet the shading is different. Why is this the case?".

Comment: Can `bezier bounding box` be used with a scope, or does it have to apply to the entire tikzpicture?

Comment: @usernumber It can (and should) be applied in a scope. The library is not perfect at this point.

Comment: Note that the `bbox` library was removed from TikZ with version 3.1.6 due to licensing issues: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/tag/3.1.6